# Mathematical notation of simulation question

Tags: notation, simulation

I would like to ask, what notation do you use, or how do you mathematically specify the following situation: I am simulating $n$ times random variable, where with probability $p$ it is $0$ and with probability $1-p$ it is $AR(2)$ process. What it is? It is somehow modified Bernoulli distribution, but I do not know how to correctly specify this simulation in my paper. Thank you for any help.

Comment: probability $p$ and $p-1$?

Comment: sorry, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Just write $X_t=YZ_t$ where $Y\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}(1-p)$ and $(Z_t)\sim AR(2)$.  If you need $n$ of them just decorate with something like $X_t^{(i)}=Y^{(i)}Z_t^{(i)}$ or you have an $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued $AR(2)$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that is exactly what I was looking for. I have just $\mathbb{R}$ process so it should be fine. I am only thinking, that it should be somehow modified because when there is $Y=1$ I want the AR(2) process to continue. Example: $X_{1} = Z_{1},$ $X_{2}=0,$ $X_{3} = Z_{2}$ not $Z_{3}$.

Comment: You have a Bernoulli process $C_t$, let $N_t=\sum_{s\leq t} C_s$ and $$X_t=\begin{cases}Z_{N_t} & C_t=1\\0 & C_t=0\end{cases}$$ or something like that.

Comment: Ones again thank you very much!